# Implementing Matrix in C but another version

Tags: c

I'm new to C programming and I am practicing on making a matrix but it is kind of different. I must only enter 1 number (e.g) 5. then the result will be

1 2 3 4 5

1 2 3 4 5

1 2 3 4 5

1 2 3 4 5

1 2 3 4 5

The colums and rows are lined 5 times. Please send help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main(){

int mat[10][10],i,j;
int num;
int nrows, ncols;

scanf("%d",&num);

for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    printf("%d",i);
    for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
        printf("%d",i);
    }
}


}
```

Comment: Array indices in C start at 0, not at 1, and go to n-1. So an array `int a[10]` has elements `0..10-1`

Comment: i am now using just two variables sir and these are

int i,j;
int num;

thanks for reminding me sir

Comment: What I mean is, your for loop should be: `for(i=0;i<num;i++)`

Comment: Instead of declaring your variables in a chaotic heap at the top, try and declare them when they're used. `i` and `j` in particular should be declared in the context of their respective loops: `for (int i = i; ...)` and so on.

Comment: note that you do not use `mat` at all (and nrows, ncols). You are not really creating a matrix just printing some numbers in a grid

Answer (score 1):

Your current code is along the right lines, but:

- The inner loop is overwriting the index of the outer loop. It should use a separate index variable e.g. the `j` you declared at the top
- Instead of writing the row number at the start of each row, print a newline character `\n` at the end

Amended:

```
for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    for(j=1;j<=num;j++){
        printf("%d",j);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: You should maybe add spacings between the columns to match OPs requirements for the output.

Comment: thank you so much sir. i know this might be so easy for you but i've been thinking about it for an hour already :( God Bless you and have a nice day ahead sir!

Comment: yes sir osiris the work is already done, im still 10 and want to learn how to code. thank you so much.

Comment: @Osiris OP did not explicitly specify that such spaces should exist (it could just be a formatting issue); however it is a trivial task.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain why they did so?